# What is this wasp killing insect?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I spotted these two in my garden.  What is this insect?  He had firm control over the wasp and was just hanging on by one leg.  He appeared to hold on until the wasp stopped moving and then flew away with it.

I live in Ohio (USA). The wasp was a bit less than 2cm long while the other insect was about 2.5cm long.

[image]

Comment: Nice pic +1! What country do you live in? What privince/state/bundesland/etc.. do you live in? What size do they have approximatively?

Comment: I'm the United States, Ohio.  The wasp was regular size, maybe 3/4 inch long and the other insect was slightly larger, maybe 1 inch long

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Given the large eyes, the almost non-existent antennae, the humped back, elongated abdomen and the wings, I'd say it is a [robber fly](http://www.realmonstrosities.com/2012/02/massive-slab-of-robber-fly.html).

[image]

It is one of many insects known to [prey on wasps](http://animals.mom.me/natural-predators-wasps-7754.html).

Note the description on the linked page:

> This spindly piece of nastiness is a Robber Fly in the genus *Diogmites*. It seems that it's members of this particular genus that are adorned with the name *Hanging Thief*. You may remember that this was to denote *their habit of dangling from a leg or two while the other limbs held onto prey,* stabbed it to death with venom and then sucked out the insides. [Emphasis mine.]

Comment: Fun fact: They perform 'extra-oral digestion', meaning they extrude digestive enzymes onto/into their prey before ingesting them.

Not so fun fact: Those enzymes burn. I had one of these land on my arm once and try to digest me. I do not recommend it.

Comment: Interesting convergence with spiders: dangling system and extra-oral digestion.

Comment: @n_b I saw your username at the end of the post and did a double-take, thinking that it was some kind of an emoticon to express the pain.

Comment: Wow, don’t know who gave a bounty, but thanks! Hope all is well.

Comment: @anongoodnurse [Charles](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/22020/charles) gave you this bounty!

Comment: Maybe worth adding (info about the venom):  _"Robber ﬂies are capable of incapacitating large and dangerous prey quite rapidly, depending on thesite of venom injection, and they can deliver painful bites to humans . Recent studies have described over 300 venom proteins and have organized novel venoms into ﬁfteen ‘Asilidin’ protein families, using the taxa Eutolmus ruﬁbarbis,Machimus arthriticus,Dolopus genitalis, and Dasypogondiadema."_ ..

Comment: .. _"Some of these venoms are species-speciﬁc, consistent with observations of variable venom toxicity between species demonstrated by previous authors. Toxicity assays of crudevenom or isolated components have shown paralytic and other neurotoxic eﬀects in insect and mammalian subjects. "_  Source/publication:  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347161201_Pick_Your_Poison_Molecular_Evolution_of_Venom_Proteins_in_Asilidae_Insecta_Diptera

Comment: @iLuvLogix - They asked for an ID, not a lot of information on it. I tend to answer the question. The rest is superfluous.